# Outlook: scheduling recurring out-of-office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

In Outlook, is there a way (or an add-on that can do it) to schedule a recurring out-of-office message?  I work 4 10's, so I'm out of the office every Monday, and it's a bit of a pain to have to reset my out-of-office message every single week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just mark all day on Mondays as "out of the office" in your calendar?  That status will show up in Outlook and Communicator.  People shouldn't expect an "instant" response to email anyway.

Otherwise, it looks like you could get something close to work with either VBA or a custom add-in.

**EDIT:** Looks like you can get really close by using the Exchange Web Service, see [SetUserOofSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa580294.aspx).

Comment: I already to have Mondays marked as "out of office", but unfortunately most people at my company wouldn't know how to check it.  And while people *shouldn't* expect a quick response, that's rarely the case - we live in the age of Twitter where people are increasingly expecting near-instant feedback.

Comment: Great, the web services look like they'll do the trick.  Although I'll have to see if our Exchange admin will actually give me access to them :)

Answer (score 7):

I have been trying to figure this out myself all day, searching forums, and messing around with my outlook.

Finally, I figure out a work around using the rules in Outlook. Below are step by step instructions for the rule I created for an out of office reply to be sent on Tuesdays. I did test this and it did work.

This will only work as a weekly re-occurrence. I am not the most tech savvy, so someone else may be able to create a better work around for nonspecific days of the week re-occurrences.

1. Go to Rules – Then select Manage Rules and Alerts
2. Select “New Rule”
3. Select the Option “Apply rule on messages I receive” Under the category “Start from a blank rule” click next.
4. Put a check in the box – with specific words in the message header.
5. Click on the blue underlined words “specific words” a new box will pop up. In this box, type the abbreviation for the day of the week you want this to apply to. I have it set for an out of office reply on Tuesdays, the abbreviation for the days of the week are the first 3 letters, Tuesday = Tue click add, then click ok.
6. It will take you back to the previous screen, just click next.
7. Now select “have server reply using a specific message”
8. Click on the words “a specific message” in the step 2 box.
   This will open an untitled message. Leave the to, cc, and bcc blank. Fill in the subject line and the body of the email. Below is an example. Then click save and close.

My current schedule has me out of the office on Tuesdays. I will return all calls and emails on Wednesday when I return.

Thank you,
Crystal Clifford

9. This will take you back to the prior window. Make sure the information is how you want it, then click next.
10. I ran into a little snag, got caught in a loop with IT because we both had an auto reply set up. You can probably do the “except if it is an automatic reply” box only, but I hate bugging my IT department and I don’t want to risk another loop, so I put in a few extras.
11. Now you are at the final screen. Check your information again. You can name the rule. Make sure there is a check in the box “Turn on This Rule. Then click Finish.

Comment: This was the best answer so far!

Comment: Just a head's up that this produces unexpected results. I tried it this week because I went part-time and if someone sends you a message that is a chain of emails, it will look at the headers of all of them. Even though I was in the office today, people were getting my Out of Office message because they had forwarded me emails that had been sent on my scheduled days out of the office.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do recurring Out-of-Office

1. Create a new Calendar Invite/appointment
2. Put some subject - optional
3. Make it recurring as desired
4. In the "Show as" change the default "Busy" to "Out-of-office"
5. Save the Calendar event

Done!

I've put 4-5 everyday, when I commute as Out-Of-Office

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is simple and beautifully fast way!

Comment: Does this send an auto-reply to the sender as well?

Comment: The requestor is asking specifically about sending an automatic reply, not just setting a status.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't break any stackoverflow / superuser rules and it's also not the intention to shamelessly advertise my application.

But I have developed an online application where I try to solve this exact problem.

The tool can help you with the following situations:

- recurring out of office's for specific days / hours
- plan upfront on or more one-off out of office's
- manage multiple out of office messages

More info, [https://www.notin.today](https://www.notin.today/?utm_source=superuser.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=early_access)

bob

note: I am now looking for people who want to use this tool and give feedback. Hands-on feedback so that I can further improve the tool. Thanks!

Comment: You've clearly stated your affiliation, so no problem with linking to your project. However it would be good to add some more information on the tool such as what situations it might work for and those where it won't. (Basically increase the self-help info to link ratio.)

Comment: @mattwilkie thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible within Outlook, but if you are using Exchange Server you can schedule them all in advance.

Comment: We are using Exchange Server - but doesn't that only let you schedule a single instance at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal rule that looks at the header of a received email to see if it contains "Mon", and have the server reply with your OOO message.
[example OOO rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNXn.png)

if you want to include the weekend just add "Sat" and "Sun"

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is possible. I am not sure you can schedule OOO at all in Outlook 2007. It is a puzzling omission.