# How do I set up Outlook 2010 to send auto reply based on the time and day of the week?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, auto-reply

I need to set up an Auto reply to send messages from 6:30 pm - 6:30 am Mon-Fri and 24 hours a day Saturday and Sunday during non-supported hours.

Can Outlook 2010 be setup to send auto replies during time frames such as this?

How can it be done?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/58405/outlook-scheduling-recurring-out-of-office

Answer (score 3):

You can set up auto replies this way:

**1. Go to the `File` tab in Outlook under the `Info` menu. Press `Automatic Replies`**

[image]

**2. A window will appear, Press `Add Rule...`**

[image]

**3. Another window will appear where you can set up how you want your rule to work. In your case you will want to flag `Reply With` and select a template**

[image]

**4. You can press `Advanced...` to modify date settings as you wish.**

[image]

**5. Usually one rule will do it, but you can set up multiple rules to best suit your needs.**

Unfortunately you will not be able to specify time of day this way. A VBA script is required to reach this level of precision : This [script](https://superuser.com/questions/518729/how-do-i-set-up-outlook-to-send-a-auto-reply-during-a-certain-hour-of-the-day-ev) will give a head start if your comfortable doing a little coding.

Comment: You've done a great job of explaining and using pictures, but can you explain in more detail how this can send an auto reply "6:30 pm - 6:30 am Mon-Fri and 24 hours a day Saturday and Sunday"?

Comment: You would get to step 3 and tick `Sent directly to me` and or `Copied to me`, then you would set up what your actions are. In your case I would say tick `Reply with` and choose a template if you wish or you can input plain text in step 2 under `Auto reply once...`. In step 4 you would set your `Received` date range from Monday 6:30pm to Friday 6:30am. For saturday and sunday you would create a second rule with that range specified. Once this is all done tick `I am currently out of office` in step 2

Comment: This will allow me select dates, what I really need is to be able to send it Mon - Fri 6:30pm - 6:30 am and 24 hours on Saturday and Sunday regardless of the calendar date (7/22/13)

Comment: Unfortunately outlook doesn't have a built in feature for this, for time of day you may need to run a VBA script. I will update my answer to reflect this limitation.