# Recurring out of office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I work three days a week and need to set an out of office for Mondays and Thursdays, but I do not remember to set it each Friday and Wednesday before I leave. Can I set up a recurring out of office for just these days?

Comment: This is not possible in Outlook, a script can be thought off, but this would need to run as a scheduled task either on the server or on a server/computer with the management tools. i can give an example if you want, which version of exchange is it?  also see: http://superuser.com/questions/58405/outlook-scheduling-recurring-out-of-office?rq=1

Comment: Hi CharlieRB, I have tried it but need further clarification on exactly how to do it because I cannot see the options for it in the out of office. However I do not have enough experience to leave a comment on the post you linked to asking for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to make a scheduled task and you have sufficient permissions to do this you could use this script.
If you make 2 scripts you can schedule script 1 to run on Wednesday 5pm(?) and then set the part where it says `.AddDays(1)` to 2.
and you can make the other script to run on Friday 5PM(?) and set the `adddays` thing to 4

```powershell
$identity = "email address"
$autoReplyState = "Scheduled"
$externalMessage = "Enter a message shown to people outside of your domain"
$internalMessage = "Enter a message shown to people inside of your domain"

#this means it will start now
$startTime = Get-Date
#this means it will end now + 1 day
$endTime = $startTime.AddDays(1)

# Import the Exchange Modules

## This part is is for Exchange 2010, Required managements tools to be installed.
## remove the # at the start of the next line if you wish to use exchange 2010
# add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

##This part is for Exchange 2013/2016
 $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ExchangeServer/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
 Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking


Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity $identity -AutoReplyState $autoReplyState -StartTime $startTime -EndTime $endTime -InternalMessage $internalMessage -ExternalMessage $externalMessage
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I do not think I am going to have the permissions to do this. We have permissions to nothing where I work.